# The action of UIBarbuttonItem on UIToolBar not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am having trouble as the action of UIBarbuttonItem on UIToolBar is not be called.
In the following code, although the `doneBtn` on `toolBar` is tapped, the action `doneBtnAction:` is not be called.
Do you have any idea to fix it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -44, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolBar.items = @[flex, doneBtn];
    [pickerView addSubview:toolBar];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.inputView = pickerView;
}

- (void)doneBtnAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
}
```

Comment: Do you see the `doneBtn` animate the tap? How is the `toolBar` positioned within the `pickerView`?

Comment: Debug view hierarchy for frame of `UIPickerView`、`UIToolbar`、`UITextField`. Hope help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't add the toolbar as a subview of the picker view, especially with a negative y origin (No touches reach the toolbar because the taps are clipped to the picker view's frame).

Instead, make the toolbar the `inputAccessoryView` of the text field.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Complete code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneBtnAction:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    toolBar.items = @[flex, doneBtn];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    textField.inputView = pickerView;
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
}
```

One other note - Why not use the standard system Done type for the bar button item?

Comment: This problem was resolved thanks to your support. Thank you.